# How to get output from shell script on mac?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I am looking to run a command in shell script and check its output.If it has certain text, I want to set a global variable to particular string.Below is what I have done so far.
The command `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android list | grep 'The "android" command is deprecated.` works in terminal however it doesn't seem to work in shell script.
What am I missing here?

```
#!/bin/bash
Android_Command=''    

MKCOMMAND='~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android list | grep 'The "android" command is deprecated.''
RESP=$($MKCOMMAND)
echo $RESP

if [ '$RESP'=='The "android" command is deprecated.' ]; then
 Android_Command='Version2'
else
 Android_Command='Version1'
fi
```

Following is the output that I get

```
 ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Describe 'doesn't work'. Also the code you've shown contains a newline and quotes that probably don't work (you can't use single quotes inside single quotes)

Comment: doesn't work means it doesn't execute through shell script. although it executes on terminal and gives relevant output

Comment: Your terminal will use whatever shell is in the shebang. However, what shell does the shell script use to run it? And what is the error message you get?

Comment: My shell script file has .command extension.I just double click it to run it

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and edit your question with the relevant details. In particular, run the script in terminal and note the outputs. Perhaps add a few more debugging echoes like for instance echo $MKCOMMAND.

Comment: You get that output because you enclosed `~` in single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last edit, it has become clear that you were not executing the script from your terminal but rather you were just executing a single line from it.

In shell scripts, anything inside a single quote is not subject to shell expansion. Having said that, both `~` and `|` cannot be quoted.

Redirections are created by the shell before execution. This means `MKCOMMAND` cannot be executed because the pipe `|` will be treated as a parameter to the command `android`.

So how do we deal with this kind of script? Don't quote any redirections.

```
#!/bin/bash

if ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android list | grep -q 'The "android" command is deprecated.'; then
 Android_Command='Version2'
else
 Android_Command='Version1'
fi
```

The `if` statement accepts a complex statement. `grep -q` will return zero if it finds the string and non-zero otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Try running your command directly instead (without using the `MKCOMMAND` variable):

```
RESP=$(~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android list | grep 'The "android" command is deprecated.')
echo $RESP
...
```

This (quick!) hack might bypass some Bash *quoting* issues you may be having.

Comment: Not clear why the *downvote*... this seems to be working just fine here ;)